# Entity Framework: EF gets related objects of an entity in different order

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I'm working with MVC3 and Entity Framework 4.0. The situation is the following: I have an entity called "Topics" and a related entity called "Questions". To visualize the questions I have a Topics view and then in a foreach sentence inside the view, show the Questions related to that topic:

`foreach(Questions Question in Topic.Questions)
{
//Show question info
}`

But anytime a question is updated in another view, when I go to the Topic view, the questions appear in a diferent order, most specifically, the question that was updated appears first.

Anyone knows why is this behavior?. And how to stop it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using a query something like this:

```
context.Topics.Include( o => o.Questions )...
```

You can't specify the order of included tables in EF, but you can still use LINQ to objects.

So just change your `foreach` to:

```
foreach ( Question question in topic.Questions.OrderBy( ...required order... ) )
```